# Custom naming in Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have auto generated legacy MS SQL database with encoded column and table names, and text file with codes and description of corresponding tables and columns. 
Is is possible to use names from text file on model creating using Entity Framework database first?

Comment: If you want database first, why don't you use the structure of the database?

Comment: What does the text file look like?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing built-in that will do that for you.  You can write a program that reads the text file and outputs a C# code file with the entity definitions and mapping attributes.

Comment: If he used a T4 template, it's answer of *sorta* because the T4 template runs before the code compiles to build the entities, but it's still code that has to be written :)

Comment: +1 T4 is probably the best language to write this in, as it's designed for this sort of thing and integrated with Visual Studio.